# Highmaps - Issue with Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, charts, highcharts, internet-explorer-11, highmaps

I am using Highmaps for creating map charts.

Here are my import : `highcharts.js`, `map.js`, `data.js`, `world.js`, `exporting.js` and `charts.js`.

Here is my code

```
var mapChart = $('#chartContainer0').highcharts('Map', {
          title : {
              text : 'Geographical Distribution'
          },
          subtitle:{
              text : 'Total IEs'
          },
          series : [{
                       data : data,
                       mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
                       joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code']

                   }]
        });
```

Note : Here data is Key : value pair where key is country code and value is number of entity in that perticular country.

Now problem is chart is drawing fine in all browsers except the mighty `Internet Explorer`. Problem is in `IE` the related countries are not filled in with colour.

Here is chrome's result

[image]

Here is IE's result

[image]

Is there any additional file needed for IE? Or is there any other workaround?

Comment: Any errors in the IE console?

Comment: @wergeld No errors in IE console.

Comment: Can you put up a fiddle with some of your data to reproduce the error? What version of IE?

Comment: @wergeld IE version 11. I will make a fiddle and post it.

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Darshan007/a0vphm6t/2/

Comment: @wergeld JsFiddle is working fine in IE but my project is not. Any idea? :)

Comment: How we can replicate your issue, have you any live demo of unworking chart?

Comment: @SebastianBochan I do not have a working demo right now but I'll try to make one. For now, can you just tell me that my `imports` and `code` is right? Or any additional file will be needed for `IE`?

Comment: It looks like correct and you dont need an extra file for IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue

Actually I was missing the comma in the data

```
 data = [
   {
       "code": "KE"
       "value": 728
   },
   {
       "code": "BR"
       "value": 710
   },
   {
       "code": "NP"
       "value": 963
   }

 ];
```

The data should be like

```
{
       "code": "NP",
       "value": 963
}
```

It was working fine for `chrome`, `firefox`, `safari` and even `edge`. Only `IE` has issue with it. Hail `IE`!!!